# I use Jinja2 "recursive" tag in my code,but how can I get the depth of current loop?

Tags: python, jinja2

I use the tag "recursive" as the documentation:

```
<ul class="sitemap">
{%- for item in sitemap recursive %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.href|e }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {%- if item.children -%}
        <ul class="submenu">{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
    {%- endif %}</li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

but I want to know the depth of current loop and the parent loop index.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try an array of `loop.index` values where the parent index is saved before each call to loop() and popped immediately after.  To modify an array without rendering text, enable `{% do ... %}` statements.

Example:

```
template = """
{%- set idxs = [0] -%}
{%- for item in sitemap recursive %}
    depth={{idxs|length}}. idx={{loop.index}}. pidx={{idxs[-1]}}. title={{item.title}}
    {%- if item.children -%}
        {%- do idxs.append(loop.index) -%}
        {{ loop(item.children) }}
        {%- do idxs.pop() -%}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
"""

class Node():
    def __init__(self, title, children=[]):
        self.title = title
        self.children = children

sitemap = [
    Node('a', [
        Node('a_a', [
            Node('a_a_a'),
            ]),
        Node('a_b', [
            Node('a_b_a', [
                Node('a_b_a_0'),
                ]),
            ]),
        ]),
    Node('b'),
    ]

env = jinja2.Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.do'])
print env.from_string(template).render(sitemap=sitemap)
```

This program prints:

```
    depth=1. idx=1. pidx=0. title=a
    depth=2. idx=1. pidx=1. title=a_a
    depth=3. idx=1. pidx=1. title=a_a_a
    depth=2. idx=2. pidx=1. title=a_b
    depth=3. idx=1. pidx=2. title=a_b_a
    depth=4. idx=1. pidx=1. title=a_b_a_0
    depth=1. idx=2. pidx=0. title=b
```